# Run Background Task at specific time - Windows 10 App

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp, background-task

I've searched a way to run a Background Task daily at a specific time, e.x. at at 12:00.

I've registered the BackgroundTask with a TimeTrigger, which unfortunately starts immediately after registering.

```
builder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(24 * 60, false));
```

Is there a easier way, then checking every hour, if this is the right time of day?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft seems to avoid apps from triggering at a precise time, but you might be able to get close by calculating the number of minutes from the time the user registers the task to 12:00, then resubscribe another task from there set for 24*60 as you have. I'm unsure if Microsoft allows this within a Background task, but it's worth a shot.

Example of calculating the minutes to midnight for the task

```
var tommorowMidnight = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
var timeTilMidnight = tommorowMidnight - DateTime.Now;
var minutesTilMidnight = (uint)timeTilMidnight.TotalMinutes;
builder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(minutesTilMidnight, true));
```

Comment: This sounds interesting, I will try it.

Comment: Does this actually work more than once? I thought the Freshness time was how often something would occur not what time it will occur.
So say it is 10:30AM and I want to run a task at 12:00
I can work out that 12:00 is 90 minutes away.
Except as far as I can tell the task will then run ever 90 minutes not every day at 12:00???

Answer (score -1):

I've used this task wrapper to create something like this before and it fired everyday. Maybe this is what you are looking for.

http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/

Comment: Is this avaible for Windows 10 Apps, too? I think it only supports Desktop Applications.